# ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=ITALY throws ORA-00911

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, system.data.oracleclient

If I try to execute the statement `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=ITALY` in SQL Developer, I get no errors. But if I run it through a Win Forms application of mine, connecting through the System.Data.OracleClient provider, I get the "ORA-0911: invalid character" error. Why? My version of Oracle is 10.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I was executing

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=ITALY;
pl/sql block: DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END;
/
```

I removed the semicolon and replaced it with

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=ITALY
/
pl/sql block: DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END;
/
```

and it works now

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it in execute immediate:

```
execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=ITALY';
```